# How do libraries like Firebase catch exceptions without adding one line of code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-crash-reporting

I was installing Firebase today, and their documentation basically says, add the firebase-crash dependency to your app dependencies, and then it works out of the box without adding any line of code. It will automatically catch all the uncaught exceptions by itself.

Now I know that I would have to use `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler` if I am to set bug catching on my own, but how Firebase did it without being ever referenced in my application? How is it able to get the current Thread and how does it run?

Firebase doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/crash/android